# Jasmine Unit Tests in an angular 1.4 app + Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, jasmine, karma-runner

I am building an angular app which uses Firebase as the front-end. But i am unable to see how to implement unit tests for the Firebase code in my app.

In conclusion, my question is:

### How do you implement Firebase testing in an angular app?

As an example could someone unit test the following method?

```
    service.subscribeForEvent = function (eventKey) {
              service.dbRef = firebase.database().ref(eventKey);

              service.dbRef.on('value', function (result) {
                onMessage(result.val());
              });
            };

I have created a fake of firebase: 
firebase = {
    __ref: {
      events: {
        'child_added': [],
        'child_changed': []
      },

      push: function (data) {
        angular.forEach(this.events["child_added"], function (each) {
          each(data);
        });
      },

      update: function (data) {
        angular.forEach(this.events["child_changed"], function (each) {
          each(data);
        });
      },

      child: function () {
        return {
          on: function (eventType, callback) {
            window.firebase.__ref.events[eventType].push(callback);
          }
        };
      }
    },

    database: function () {
      return {
        ref: function () {
          return window.firebase.__ref;
        },

        $clean: function () {
          window.firebase.__ref.events['child_added'] = [];
          window.firebase.__ref.events['child_changed'] = [];
        }
      };
    };
```

and expect after new child is added in firebase, the callback function to be called:

```
it('subscribe for added event and receive message for it', function () {
      var eventName = 'new event';
      var callback = jasmine.createSpy('callback');

      pushApi.bind(eventName, callback);

      ref.push({
        val: function () {
          return {event: {key: eventName}};
        }
      });

      expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith({key: eventName});
    };
```

But when run test it expected default firebase to be created.

Comment: Break down your problem. What exactly are you having trouble testing? Whatever your answer is, can it be broken down further? Find the first thing you can't test, and figure out why you can't. I'd comment out all your code but the simplest thing and add a test for it. Then uncomment the next simplest thing, and add a test. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I created fake for firebase and add listeners. I want to test that callback will be called when some happened in database. But i am not able to find any examples how to that.

Comment: Please update your question with the simplest test that demonstrates the problem you are having. I see roughly four or five tests that should exist for that one function.